# Using GoogleMaps, or Bing pseudo-commercially?

Tags: google-maps, bing-maps

I have an app for which I have extensive use of geocoding, and map plotting.  I'd like to make money off it, but not pay the $10k tax since I'm a little guy.

I was thinking about offering the mapping aspects of the app for free, but charge for additional add-ons/features.

Would this be breaking the google licensing?

Comment: A legal question? What does this have to do with programming?

Answer (score 1):

You can normally use the free Google Maps API if your Maps API implementation is generally accessible to users without charge. You may require users to log in to a section in your website where you would have the Maps API Implementation, but you must not require users to pay a fee. ([Google Maps API Terms of Service](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/terms.html))

Unless you have entered into a [separate written agreement with Google](http://www.google.com/enterprise/earthmaps/maps.html) or obtained Google's written permission, your Maps API Implementation must not:

1. require a fee-based subscription or other fee-based restricted access; or
2. operate only behind a firewall or only on an internal network (except during the development and testing phase).

In addition you mentioned that your application will use geocoding extensively. [Server-side geocoding](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/) with the free Maps API has a limit of 15,000 request per IP address per day. ([Google Maps API FAQ](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/faq.html#geocoder%5Flimit))

I would suggest getting in touch with Google first, describing your application. They should be able to classify if your application can work within the terms of the free Maps API or not.

Comment: +1 for getting in touch with Google. Much cheaper than getting a lawyer and probably more effective.